# tags webscrapping, scraping e webcrawler

Tags: debate, status-recusado, tags, tags-sinônimas

Gostaria de sugerir como sinônimos as seguintes tags:

- [webscrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webscrapping) - 10 perguntas
- [scraping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraping) - 8 perguntas
- [web-crawler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) - 25 perguntas

Acho que a junção destas tags vai auxiliar bastante quem acompanha perguntas deste tipo e vai agilizar as respostas.

Comment: Todas parecem realmente que no nosso site sempre se enquadram, mas acho que temos que tomar cuidado http://stackoverflow.com/q/4327392/1518921

Comment: São coisas diferentes mesmo, mas como o uso no site não é correto, não sei o que é melhor: tudo ser sinônimo (uma vez que são assuntos correlatos) ou ser separado e alguém ter que ficar arrumando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [webscrapping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webscrapping) - é a técnica
- [scraping](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scraping) - pode ser feito fora da web
- [web-crawler](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) - é a ferramenta

As *tags* podem estar sendo usadas de forma equivocada e aconselho editar as perguntas erradas com as *tags* certas. Mas elas não são sinônimos.

Comment: De fato. E um web-crawler pode fazer outras coisas que não envolvem scraping. Medidas de tempo de acesso, simples confirmação de existência, teste de cache etc. - Da mesma forma posso fazer webscraping com uma mera extensão de browser, sem um webcrawler específico.

Comment: Agora, precisa de qualquer forma de uma correção de grafia, pq **scraping** é com um P só, e **webscrapping** foi grafado com dois. O uso de `-` ou não em `web-scraping` deve ser averiguado também. Acredito que seja mais apropriado separado.

Comment: @Bacco feito!..